# Remove Shadow from Black and White filter using GPUImage

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, gpuimage, imagefilter

I am trying to apply black and white filter and i have succeded in same but after filter i am having shadow which disturbs whole filter , so i wanted to remove or lighten shadow ,so is anyone having ideawhat should i do.?

attaching the code i have implemented and Output at of same

[image]

```
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];


GPUImageContrastFilter * stillImageContrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc]init];
stillImageContrastFilter.contrast = 1.0;

GPUImageSharpenFilter * stillImageSharpenFilter = [[GPUImageSharpenFilter alloc]init];
stillImageSharpenFilter.sharpness = 4.0;

GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * stillImageBlurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc]init];
stillImageBlurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 1.0;

GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter * stillImageThresFilter = [[GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter alloc]init];
stillImageThresFilter.thresholdMultiplier = 0.88;

GPUImageChromaKeyFilter * stillImageSmoothFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyFilter alloc]init];
stillImageSmoothFilter.smoothing = 0.1f;

[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageContrastFilter];
[stillImageContrastFilter addTarget:stillImageSharpenFilter];
[stillImageSharpenFilter addTarget:stillImageBlurFilter];
[stillImageBlurFilter addTarget:stillImageThresFilter];
[stillImageThresFilter addTarget:stillImageSmoothFilter];



[stillImageSmoothFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *imgTmp1 = [stillImageSmoothFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Comment: hi, please share code if you solved it.

Comment: @ChanWarde pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714561/opencv-how-to-apply-adaptive-threshold-to-an-image-on-ios/43912645#43912645

Comment: I used that, but I want to remove that light shadow from the image. In my case, I only want to show color with the equal colored background.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a constant threshold on the image using a `GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter`. If illumination varies across your piece of paper, the darker areas will fall below the threshold and the brighter ones pass above it.

What you want is a threshold that adapts to local conditions. That's what the `GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter` does. It performs a box blur on the area around each pixel, determines the average luminance from that, and if the pixel is above this luminance it is marked as white. Otherwise, black.

Most people who do the kind of business card scan enhancement you're attempting here apply a filter like that instead of an image-wide threshold.

Comment: hey Brad can you help me some sort of code as i am new to this filter thing